# Is the Loaders only for reading data from the database and not for updating and deleting data?

Tags: android, loader

I'm a Android newbie and currently trying to convert my app so that it uses Loaders to interact with the database so that I can work in the background.

I already have a few methods which query and update the database so I'm thinking of moving them all to the OnCreateLoader method.

The only problem is the OnCreateLoader method expects to return a CursorLoader and the CursorLoader automatically  calls a ContentResolver's query method.

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
```

How am I supposed to get a CursorLoader to call the ContentResolver's update or insert methods?

Or am I not supposed to use a Loader for those queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Loader`s are for reading data - [AsyncQueryHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) is the built in class designed specifically for doing insert/update/deletes easily:

```
new AsyncQueryHandler(context.getContentResolver()){
    @Override
    onInsertComplete(int token, Object cookie, Uri uri)
    {
        // Insert completed successfully
    }
}.startInsert(0,    // token, used to distinguish inserts in onInsertComplete
              null, // cookie, used to distinguish inserts in onInsertComplete 
              uri,  // URI to update
              initialValues); // ContentValues to pass to your ContentProvider
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now, `CursorLoader` only supports reading of data. If you want to do updating data, you might want to look into writing your own [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html).

Or, check out [CWAC LoaderEx](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) which seems to have done all this for you.